# Click radio button of html web table- Java

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, html-table, webdriver

My question is how do i click the radio button of html web table?

Additional info:

My code works just fine however I cant click the radio button of selected column/row using xpath. The xpath I am using within the loop is not working. However the xpaths I am using work individually in the Chrome browser. I am thinking feel I need to join both together but that did not work probably because i am not an expert in using xpath.  I have been working on this for the past 24 hours and no solution. I have search for a solution on stackoverflow but have not found anything similar.

```
radio button xpath:
//TBODY[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_tbody']/TR[7]/TD[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]
```

my code is:

```
List < WebElement > payDates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_table']//tr[position()>1]/td[position()=5]"));

         //** Begin third inner for-loop****
         for (WebElement pd: payDates) {
          System.out.println("sample1-> " + pd.getText());

          SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
          Date payDate = dateFormat.parse(pd.getText());
          System.out.println("sample-> " + dateFormat.format(payDate));

          if (payDate.after(new Date())) {
           System.out.println("inside for loop");

           String radiobutton = "//TBODY[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_tbody']/TR[7]/TD[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]";
           WebElement calrow = driver.findElement(By.xpath(pd + radiobutton));
           calrow.click();
```

pd in the loop should already contain the correct link i am thinking because it is looping through all the dates in payDates.

HTML code i loop through this is just a sample.

```
<td id="changeStartWeekGrid_row_1_cell_4" style="" align="left" class="table-grid-cell OUTPUT_TEXT" title=""><span>03/02/2018</span></td>
```

HTML radio button

```
<div class="revitRadioButtonIcon"></div>
```

Comment: I can't validate that your xpath is correct or not without seeing at least the relevant segment of HTML code for the page.  The fact that the division does not contain at least an image might be a clue.

Comment: I actually found what i needed this was my answer //table[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_table']//span[text()='"+dateFormat.format(payDate)+"']/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td//div[@class='revitRadioButtonIcon']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found what i needed this was my answer `//table[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_table']//span[text()='"+dateFormat.format(payDate)+"']/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td//div[@class='revitRadioButtonIcon']`

If found out that you use preceding-sibling::td// to go back and td/following-sibling::td// to go forward here is another example

`element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td//*[contains(text(),'Regular Hours')]//ancestor::td/following-sibling::td//*[contains(@class,'reactTextBox')]"))`;